# From Laserscan to obstacle avoidance

Tags: navigation, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have got the laser scan from the kinect using the openni_driver. Now i would like to use it for obstacle avoidance. For obstacle avoidance, i am using vector field histogram. Any suggestions or directions i could take?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10634/from-laserscan-to-obstacle-avoidance/) by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2011-07-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question is overly generic.  Please take a look at the [navigation stack](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation) There are lots of tutorials and documentation on how to use the existing implementations to do path planning with obstacle avoidance.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-07-20**:
I would like to explain in more in detail. I am putting a kinect camera on UAV and using it for obstacle avoidance. Hence, the UAV has no sonar and odometer. I am using VFH to do obstacle avoidance.I have downloaded the vfh.cc to do obstacle avoidance but not really sure how to use it...

**Comment by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) on 2011-07-20**:
You could adhere to the base local planner interface when writing your VFH implementation in order to take advantage of all the other components the navigation stack has to offer. You may find the nav_core package interesting: http://www.ros.org/wiki/nav_core

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-07-20**:
Thanks for the package. But i am using vector field histogram for obstacle avoidance. how does this link with the navigation stack? i am not sure abt it...

**Comment by [q8wwe](https://answers.ros.org/users/38902/q8wwe/) on 2020-01-25**:
Where you able to use VFH with kinect